# MS Access ACCDE will not compile, syntax error

Tags: vba, ms-access, compilation

I am brand new to ms access, and I am having a syntax error that is preventing me from compiling my db into an executable accde. I'm sure it's something simple I'm looking over.

[image: Code:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your first red line, put a space then underscore at the end.

```
If IsNull(Me.OrderDeliveryDate) Or _
IsNull(Me.OrderDeliveryDate) Then
```

Or, just use

```
If IsNull(Me.OrderDeliveryDate) Then
```

because the second condition is redundant.